# Print and write the WKB to another shapefile using OGR_G_ExportToWKB in C?

Tags: gdal, ogr, well-known-binary, c

I want to convert the geometry to well known binary (WKB) format of my shapefile. I want to print and want to write it into another shapefile.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ogr_api.h>
#include <cpl_conv.h>
#include <cpl_port.h>
#include <gdal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gdal_utils.h>
#include <cpl_progress.h>
#include <cpl_minixml.h>
#include <ogr_core.h>
int main()
{
    char path1[200],path2[200],filename1[]="/1.shp",filename2[]="/g_copy.shp";
    unsigned char *buf;
    char *sz;
    GDALDatasetH inShapeDS;
    OGRLayerH inShapeLayer;
    OGRFeatureH inShapeFeature;
    OGRFeatureDefnH inFeatureDefn;
    OGRFieldDefnH inFieldDefn;

    int inFieldCount;
    OGRGeometryH inShapeGeometry;

    GDALAllRegister();

    getcwd(path1, sizeof(path1));
    strcpy(path2,path1);
    strcat(path1,filename1);
    strcat(path2,filename2);

    inShapeDS = GDALOpenEx(path1, GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    if( inShapeDS == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Open failed.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    printf("number of layers:%d\n",GDALDatasetGetLayerCount(inShapeDS));

    inShapeLayer = GDALDatasetGetLayerByName(inShapeDS, "1");

    inFeatureDefn = OGR_L_GetLayerDefn(inShapeLayer);
    printf("number of features in this layer:%d\n",OGR_L_GetFeatureCount(inShapeLayer,1));  

    inShapeFeature = OGR_L_GetNextFeature(inShapeLayer);

    inShapeGeometry = OGR_F_GetGeometryRef(inShapeFeature);

    printf("size of binary geom:%d\n",OGR_G_WkbSize(inShapeGeometry));  

    buf = (unsigned char *)CPLMalloc(OGR_G_WkbSize(inShapeGeometry));

    OGR_G_ExportToWkb(inShapeGeometry,wkbXDR,buf);

    //sz=buf;
    sz = (char *)buf;

    printf("binary geom:%s",sz);


    const char *pszDriverName = "ESRI Shapefile";
    GDALDriverH outDriver;
    GDALDatasetH outDS;
    OGRLayerH outLayer;
    OGRFieldDefnH outFieldDefn;


    outDriver = GDALGetDriverByName( pszDriverName );
    if( outDriver == NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s driver not available.\n", pszDriverName );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    outDS = GDALCreate( outDriver, path2, 0, 0, 0, GDT_Unknown, NULL );
    if( outDS == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Creation of output file failed.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    outLayer = GDALDatasetCreateLayer( outDS, "g_copy", NULL, wkbUnknown, NULL );
    if( outLayer == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Layer creation failed.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    outFieldDefn = OGR_Fld_Create( "GeomB", OFTString );
    OGR_Fld_SetWidth( outFieldDefn, (OGR_G_WkbSize(inShapeGeometry)));
    if( OGR_L_CreateField( outLayer, outFieldDefn, TRUE ) != OGRERR_NONE )
    {
        printf( "Creating Name field failed.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    OGR_Fld_Destroy(outFieldDefn);

    OGRFeatureH outFeature;
    outFeature = OGR_F_Create( OGR_L_GetLayerDefn( outLayer ) );
    OGR_F_SetFieldString( outFeature, OGR_F_GetFieldIndex(outFeature, "GeomB"), sz );

    if( OGR_L_CreateFeature( outLayer, outFeature ) != OGRERR_NONE )
    {
        printf( "Failed to create feature in shapefile.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    OGR_F_Destroy( outFeature );

    CPLFree(buf);
    OGR_F_Destroy(inShapeFeature);

    GDALClose(inShapeDS);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is in print function, it is giving some symbol. And in the newly created shapefile, it is not printing anything. Another thing that in the new shapefile the width of the GeomB field is truncated to 254, but the width of binary version of the geom is almost 2000 bits.

It is getting very much difficult in C. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

#### OGRwkbByteOrder

([docs on eByteOrder](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a36cc1f4d807ba8f6fb8951f3adf251e2))

You are likely wanting to use `wkbNDR`, which is `enum` 1, assuming you are running on an intel architecture.

#### invalid conversion error

([docs on OGR_G_ExportToWkb()](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__api_8h.html#ad5c94ae76c09774dba8725c24daeefd6))

Without having the full error message, it looks like `OGR_G_ExportToWkb()` takes an `unsigned char*`, and you dereference `buf` (which is an `unsigned char*`) to become an `unsigned char`. I think it should look like this:

```
OGR_G_ExportToWkb(inShapeGeometry,eOrder,buf);
```

([docs on OGR_G_ExportToWkt()](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__api_8h.html#a3bc9310302e2dbfaab1690de9e2fd2fb))

For `OGR_G_ExportToWkt()`, it looks like the buffer is specified as a `char**`, or a pointer to a char-pointer. In your case, you should provide the address of the `char*` `buff`. What you are currently doing is dereferencing `buff`, which provides a `char`.

```
OGR_G_ExportToWkt(inShapeGeometry,&buff);
```

#### Proper functioning

This is the baseline to get the program **compiling**, I think. If you look at the docs, you will see a better description of what these buffers are doing. In the case of `exportToWkb()`, you need to ensure the buffer is atleast `OGRGeometry::WkbSize()` long, so declaring the length of the buffer at the top of the program might not be the best idea (or maybe 100 characters is fine if you have a very small geometry set). In the case of `exportToWkt()`, a new `char` buffer is created by the function and the `char**` (`&buff` for you) is set to point to that buffer. This means you don't need to allocate memory for `buff` at the top of the program. Just make `buff` an unassigned `char**`.

```
// stuff
char** buff;

//stuff

OGR_G_ExportToWkt(inShapeGeometry, buff);
```

Comment: modified the code in my question. Please check again.

Comment: @LSG The error message says it all. The compiler is unable to convert an `unsigned char` into an `unsigned char*`. You are still dereferencing `buf` in the call to `OGR_G_ExportToWkb(inShapeGeometry,wkbNDR,*buf);` When you put an asterisk before `buf` you are returning an `unsigned char`. The function needs an `unsigned char*`. Do not put the asterisk in front of `buf`.

Comment: Ok, tried with that, but it got hanged. Now tried again without the print and it is fine. So, some problem with the print. `printf("binary geom:%s",*buf); --> stopped working, printf("binary geom:%s",buf); --> prints symbol, printf("binary geom:%c",*buf); -->prints symbol, printf("binary geom:%u",*buf); --> prints 1`. What is this 1?

Comment: Edited a lot in the code

Comment: @LSG Printing an array of char (binary data) won't always behave like you expect. `printf` needs to be null-terminated, I think. Don't print `buf`. Write it to a file. Look at the WKB format standard to understand what WKB looks like and how it does not look like a string of chars.

Comment: I have tried to write in a new shapefile earlier. Nothing showed. And now, tried to run in a text file. It is showing 0 if I use %u and null if I use %s